# Get Sub-Menu Dropdown to Show Over Page Content

Tags: menus, css

I'm using the Avada theme and when i recently did an update, my sub-menu did something weird.

Take a look at [my website](http://bonsecours.org/). check the secondary navigation ( The one in the light blue that holds the links to "Justice Peace & Integrity", "Congregation Leadership", and "International Committees" ).

The first link (Justice, Peace, ...) actually has two pages underneath it so when you hover over the link, you should see the two pages but instead you can only see the top of one link.

I applied `position:relative` to the sub-menu class and that made my drop downs appear but it also expanded the background which doesn't look good.

Any suggestions on what I could do? I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an overflow issue with your menu items. To solve it, head over to `Appearance > Customize` and add this piece of CSS to your custom CSS:

```
.fusion-main-menu{
    overflow:visible!important
}
```

This will allow your submenu to overlap the DIV while hovered.

Comment: You're the real MVP!!! That did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @Kizzie No problem mate. Happy to hear it worked for you.